# Character return line break lost when sending text to web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a C# web service (very basic, made with VS) and a C# client.

The web service runs SQL Server stored procedures.

CRLF in text sent to web service is lost by the time it gets to the stored procedures.

Annoyingly, I cannot debug or alter the server.

Is there something I can do to the client to make it send CRLF in such a way that they are not lost?

Comment: what do you mean by lost? is it the encoding?

Comment: Well, there are CRLF in text in the client and the same text but without CRLF in the stored procedure.